# Using enum in generic expression to define return types

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to use generics to get return value based upon enum argument.

```
public enum DataTypes {
   MEAL, EXAM_RESULT, SPORTS,ECA, HEATLH;
}


public class GeneralData{
    String getDataFile();
}

public class SportsData extends GeneralData{
    getDailyCalroiesBurnt();
    getSwimmingStyle();
}

public class HealthData extends GeneralData{
    getBloodGroup();
}
```

Now I want to write a function "getData(DataTypes datatype)" which

- when called with DataTypes.SPORTS returns SportsData object
- when called with DataTypes.HEATLH returns HealthData object
- for all other returns GeneralData object.

Something like :

```
<T> T getData(DataTypes datatype){
    ...
    ...
}

HealthData healthData = getData(DataTypes.HEATLH);
SportsData sportsData = getData(DataTypes.SPORTS);
GeneralData examData = getData(DataTypes.EXAM_RESULT);
GeneralData mealData = getData(DataTypes.MEAL);
GeneralData ecaData = getData(DataTypes.ECA);
```

How can I do this using generics so that I don't have to do any casting? Is this even possible ?

Basically I am type to somehow statically bind enum to the object type to be returned to be used in generic expression.

Comment: Not possible in that form - what type should `getData(randomBool() ? DataTypes.SPORTS : DataTypes.HEALTH)` return?

Comment: I second the "not possible" / "doesn't make sense given Java's type system" opinion. Also this question kind of gets asked a million times.

Answer (score 1):

Variant types in Java, and most other widely used programming languages, are a pain in the ass.  See my [blog post](http://jazzjuice.blogspot.com/2010/10/6-things-i-hate-about-java-or-scala-is.html) which demonstrates about 8 ways to do variants.

In your specific case, you are never going to achieve the last five lines of code you demonstrate.  The best you can hope for is to always get a `GeneralData` and "interrogate" it in a type safe way (by using a Visitor pattern, for example).

Answer (score 1):

I'd pass the class objects instead:

```
<T extends GeneralData> T getData(Class<T> clazz);
```

Then you can do:

```
SportsData sportsData = readData(SportsData.class);
HealthData healthData = readData(HealthData.class);
```

Comment: How will you implement getData ()?  It's easy to write a stub that will compile, but not the actual code.

Comment: I will not implement it, because the question neithers asks for that, nor provides sufficient information to do so (in particular, the format of the data file is unknown). I also don't see any particular difficulty in implementing this method. If you do, feel free to point it out, so I may adress it in my answer.

Comment: @JudgeMental: The implementation can use, for example, a `Map<Class<? extends GeneralData>, GeneralData>`, and use `clazz.cast()` to be type-safe to some extent. The type system won't guarantee the behaviour is correct "all the way down" but if a type error occurs it will be a failed cast at a location a cast is actually seen occuring. (The problem "unchecked cast" warnings are trying to prevent isn't as much code that's not provably correct by the compiler, but `ClassCastException`s occuring where none make sense.)

Comment: @JudgeMental: And at least in my opinion it's okay to use in cases like this some amount of code that's not *fully* type-safe, **if** the design calls for it (and the design is correct.) As long as it's present in small amounts, encapsulated, and makes an eventual error visible. (In my example above, a CCE when retrieving from the map tells you the contents of the map are corrupted. I'd probably also encapsulate inserting into the map with a method that takes a `Class` parameter to prevent said corruption.)

Comment: @millimoose @meriton I'm asking a thought experiment here. The only compilable implementation of the method signature given in this answer is `return null;` because once you start bifurcating based on the input you will have to cast your return value to `T` before returning it.  Not sure that's allowed.

Comment: @JudgeMental That's what [`Class.cast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) does. That's why meriton's answer consists adding the parameter `Class<T> clazz` - its purpose is "allowing" a **checked** cast to `T`. How you actually get an instance of `GeneralData` to cast is left to the OP since he never outlined his logic for creating the appropriate instance.

Comment: @JudgeMental For the sake of completeness: it is in fact possible that a better design exists for what the OP needs to achieve - so your answer also has merit. I just do recall having a genuine need to do what they're describing. (Or at least, it seemed like a better idea than spending too long figuring out what the common interface between those classes would look like.)

Comment: I had forgotten about Class.cast ().  I actually had originally suggested including the class as well but couldn't figure out how to get a real implementation to compile.  Thanks for the reminder

Comment: No, no this method can be implemented other than by `return null`. One example is the checked cast with `Class.cast()` millimoose mentions. Another is `T t = clazz.newInstance(); t.readFrom(file); return t;`. Another is `if (class == HealthData.class) return (T) new HealthData();`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

Besides, it probably not the right way to do what you want (IMO).

What would you expect the method to return if it is recieving a variable as the enum?

```
  void MyMethod(DataTypes x)
  {
        /*?*/ result = getData(x);


        // print result or whatever..
  }
```

The return type of a method is a compile-time information.
Namely, it must be known when compiling.

The value of a parameter, on the other hand, is known only at run-time.

I'm not exacly familiar with your code, but I think this is not a bad solution:

```
  HealthData healthData = getHeatlhData();
  SportsData sportsData = getSportsData();
  GeneralData examData = getData(DataTypes.EXAM_RESULT);
  GeneralData mealData = getData(DataTypes.MEAL);
  GeneralData ecaData = getData(DataTypes.ECA);
  GeneralData ecaData = getData(x);
```

I think this is reasonable.

Instead of having a lot of if-else-if's for the enum value, just have a few more methods. It's actually neat.

If your programmer know the value of the DataType he/she wants, they will use the proper method.

If it's a variable, use the general method.